# Mac system not consistently running Python 3.10; get different versions depending on how I invoke it

Tags: python, bash, macos, ksh, miniconda

I'm having trouble with multiple versions of Python on my system.  The goal would be for all of these different ways of running it always point to 3.10x

On MacOS running up-to-date Monterey.

Tests:

First 3 tests are in the bash shell.

Test 1:

```
python --version
Returns: Python 3.10.6  # so far so good
BUT this version doesn't have opencv and my other packages
```

Test 2:

```
env python --version
Python 3.8.13
```

Test 3:

```
which python
/Users/mbennett/miniconda3/bin/python
$ /Users/mbennett/miniconda3/bin/python --version
Python 3.8.13
Notice this shows 3.8, it should give back the same as just running python (test 1 above)
```

Tests for KSH + minconda setups:

Test 4:

```
This used to work, started failing today
ksh
conda activate opencv
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
$ python --version
Python 3.8.13
```

So doing stuff in Bash seems to give inconsistent results.  And now my ksh miniconda seems broken as well.

And now for miniconda, I seemed to somehow have broken that.

What I really want is:

- Python 3.10x to show up in all these places
- And hopefully recover my
  "opencv" miniconda3 environment, as it took me a long time to set
  that up.

Comment: test 1: you in main os environemnt

Test 2, you in virtual environment which has python 3.8.13 installed.

test 3, you in miniconda environment

test 4: you are in same environment, that was the version result is same

conclusion: every environment can has own version of python. it is depend which version of python you installed

Comment: Hi, I'd like to make it consistent.  Some of the tests give weird results imho

Comment: Tests 1-3 are all in the same bash session, no other commands ran in between? Maybe you have an alias set-up: what does `type python` give you?

Comment: @FlyingTeller yes the tests were one after the other.  Per your suggestion $ type python gives --> python is aliased to `/usr/local/bin/python3' and then $ /usr/local/bin/python3 --version gives --> Python 3.10.6

Comment: You have an alias set-up that points to the non-conda python installation. Is that on purpose? Do you want to use your miniconda python or your system installed python 3.10

Comment: Alias was not on perfect, I'll try to track it down.  Ideally both miniconda and the "system" python would be 3.10.  So a quick python program from bash would work, but also a complex mathematical thing under miniconda that needs lots of libraries.  I'll try to suss out that alias.  The "type" command was a good call.

Comment: OK, killed the alias, now everybody seems to be speaking 3.8; it's not 3.10, but at least it's more consistent: (base) ~ $ python --version
Python 3.8.13
(base) ~ $ which python
/Users/mbennett/miniconda3/bin/python
(base) ~ $ /Users/mbennett/miniconda3/bin/python --version
Python 3.8.13
(base) ~ $ env python
Python 3.8.13 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 25 2022, 06:06:49) 
[Clang 12.0.1 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

Comment: Now for python310, it seems to be via a "python3" script: $ python3 --version
Python 3.10.6
(base) ~ $ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3
(base) ~ $ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.10.6
(base) ~ $ type python3
python3 is hashed (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3)
but certainly not in miniconda

Comment: you can update your miniconda python by running `conda install python=3.10`